# Update in bulk in NodeJs and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm getting a data in foreach loop to which I want to perform update. One option is that I do update eveytime time in foreach loop. I don't want that.
Another is to store data is an array & the perform bulk update. But how to perform it?

Here is my data
(I'm showing 3 records here, but in actual I have 1000's of data & it's dynamic)

```
    id = 1
{ name : A , place : X , cost : 100}
id = 2
{ name : B , place : Y , cost : 200}
id = 3
{ name : C , place : Z , cost : 300}
```

Here is what I'm trying

```
pushIds = { 1, 2, 3 }
pushNames = { F, G, H }
applicationBusiness.update({id: { $in : pushIds }},  { $set: { name: pushNames },{multi:true}, (error:any, result:any) => {

});
```

Here is what I want

```
id = 1
{ name : F , place : X , cost : 100}
id = 2
{ name : G , place : Y , cost : 200}
id = 3
{ name : H , place : Z , cost : 300}
```

Comment: upsert is used to insert & update. But, I only want to update the record.

Comment: Then you should store your data in other way. For example `{id:1, name: F, place: X, cost: 100}`. Is it possible?

Comment: That is possible. But how can I perform bulk update in node then?

Comment: Have you tried  `collection.update({}, yourArray)`?